# Connecting to MongoDB remotely and getting ServerSelectioinTimeoutError

Tags: python, macos, mongodb, pymongo

New to MongoDB here and I'm having some trouble connecting to the server. I get the error ServerSelectionTimeoutError: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017:timed out

I'm using PyMongo 2.8 on OSX 10.10.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('mongodb://dba:[password]@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/Admin') #the real password has the square brackets
db = client['MyDB']
x=[]
userData = db.users.find()
for user in userData:
    x.append(user)
print x
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using an internal ip address in the client string. External ip fixed it.